# HIVE: Insert into seems to be overwriting the existing table

Tags: hive

I have a data set with around 13,000 records and I am trying to insert another data set with around 13,000 records in to the first table. I am not receiving any error messages, but the resulting table has less that 13,000 records instead of the expected 26,000.

My query looks like this

```
    insert into table base_table 
    select
    *  
    from second_table
```

Comment: Could you provide some details about the type of columns in the table? Is there an overlap in keys between the existing rows and the one's you are inserting?

Answer (score 0):

a proper query would be 
insert into tablename (field1,field2,field3) select field1,field2,field3 from tablename

do not use ID(auto increment) while inserting from same table,

and if you still face issues kindly share screenshot of error

Comment: I am not receiving any error message and I am not inserting from the same table.  Base_table and second_table have the exact same columns in the same order.                                But I will try `insert into table base_table (a,b,c)
    select
    a, b, c
    from second_table`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was making a mistake earlier on in my code that was affecting my results. After correcting that issue my original query worked. Thanks to everyone who looked at this